# How do I setup multiple project run in parallel with TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010.

I want to setup multiple projects to run in parallel with TFS 2010.

If there are 3 solutions, `TestSln / BetaSln / LiveSln`, then I want to build:

```
 TestSln with Win32/Debug configuration,
  BetaSln with x64/Debug configuration,
  LiveSln with Win32/Release configuration
  in parallel
```

1. Is it possible?
2. If possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by adding more build agents. Refer to this MSDN blog for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/09/14/parallelized-builds-with-tfs2010.aspx